# Graph Theory - Binomial Random Graphs

Tags: probability, graph-theory, expected-value, binomial-distribution, random-graphs

[image: Question 3]

Hi, could anyone provide any assistance on this? I have a feeling there's going to be a question like this on the exam and I really have no idea how to approach this concept. Any help on either part would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_{ijkl}$ denote the **indicator random variable** that with (randomly) selected nodes $i,j,k,l$ there is a 4-clique ($K_4$) in the **ER random graph** $G(n,p)$, i.e.,

$ X_{ijkl} = 
  \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if there is a }  K_4 \text{ on } i,j,k,l \\
    0, & \text{otherwise} 
  \end{cases}
  $

- Then we have $E[X_{ijkl}]=P(X_{ijkl}=1)=p^6$ (since there are ${4}\choose{2}$ $=6$ edges on a $K_4$ and they are independently drawn with probability $p$).
- Now, $E[\text{number of } K_4 \text{ in G}]$

  $= E\left[\sum\limits_{\{i,j,k,l\}}X_{ijkl}\right]=\sum\limits_{\{i,j,k,l\}}E[X_{ijkl}] \text{    }$   (by **linearity of expectation**)

  $={{n}\choose{4}}p^6 \approx n^4p^6 = (n^{2/3}p)^6$
- Hence, by **Markov inequality**, we have,

  $P(\text{number of } K_4 \geq 1) \leq \frac{E[\text{number of } K_4]}{1} \approx
    (n^{2/3}p)^6 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
- Hence $P(G \text{ contains a } K_4) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Wow thanks, it makes a lot of sense when you say it like that.

Comment: Actually, sorry I am still confused, how does (2/3)6 approach 0 as n approaches infinite? Shouldn't it approach infinite?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{p}{n^{-2/3}}\to 0$ since $p=o(n^{-2/3})$, by definition of $o(.)$

Comment: Yup, forgot that part was in the original question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First we find the probability that any set of 4 vertices is $K_4$. We say each potential edge can either be an edge in the graph (marked 1), or not (marked 0). We are given given $\mathbb P(edge=1) = p$ for all edges.

Note for any set of 4 vertices, since there are $\binom{4}{2}$ edges. $P(K_4 \text{ given 4 vertices}) = P(\text{all edges between the 4 vertices are set to 1 }) = p^{\text{no of edges}}$

Therefore, $P(K_4 \text{ given 4 vertices}) = p^{\binom{4}{2}} = p^6$.

Now
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\text{number of $K_4$ subgraphs}] &= \text{ways to choose 4 vertices}\cdot P(K_4 \text{ given 4 vertices})\\
&= \binom{n}{4}p^6
\end{align*}

---

Note that, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{4}p^6 \simeq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(n^{\frac{2}{3}}p)^6\to0$

Comment: Could you explain how that limit approaches zero? It looks like it should approach infinite